# Question about Biot Savart Law using vectors

Tags: magnetics, electricity

This is a Biot savart law question using vectors and I tried this question and I want to check my answer is correct or not. And please show me the correct answer if wrong. I uploaded my Answer.

**Question**
[image]

**My answer**

[image]

Comment: It would be much easier if you showed us your answer first since you already have it worked out. Or are you trying to trick us into doing your homework for you? Or is that your answer in the photo?

Comment: @Transistor  it's my answer

Comment: Nice job with the layout. I'll counter the downvote someone gave you but I don't think I can help with the answer.